# Configuring MakeIndex

Tags: imakeidx

I have a configuration file for the Index that runs well for latin characters but for the hebrew characters.

The .ist file is:

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\n"
postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n" 
headings_flag 1
```

Where can I find the informations to set up correctly the .ist file?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by *not running well for Hebrew characters*? What is your setup, your code? What do you observe that doesn't match your expectations?

Comment: @gernot With latin characters I have a capital letter before the index items beginning with the same letter. With the hebrew characters I have a simple list in alphabetical order and the first item is "Symbols".

Comment: Please add this information to your question, as detailed as possible. It will probably not me who will be able to answer your question.

Comment: I have found the answer to my question. I have to use xindi.